# how to simulate a escape key at the end of a key sequence in c++?

Tags: c++, escaping, keystroke

how to simulate a "escape key" as if an escape key has been pressed, at the end of a string sequence in c++?

i need to provide the stdin input, which accepts string data until Escape key is pressed,

for that it receives the characters correctly, but how do i send an 'escape key stroke' finally?

Answer (score 4):

The ASCII code for "escape" is 27 (= 1b in hex). To send an escape you just have to send that character `'\0x1b'`.